# Function doesn't work to clear out the input

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a very beginner on coding, but I have written a script, so that when I click on a button "Submit", the data entered is displayed in another tab.

Source file directly here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MOOczNf-wOZOTo0W-kbWCxkLd3M4udzJQ_fMh7xn1f4/edit#gid=0.

Unfortunately, it seems everything is working, except to clear out the cell. I have the following error message :

> ReferenceError: ClearCell is not defined.

Here the code :

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var inputS = ss.getSheetByName("Input");
  var outputS = ss.getSheetByName("Output");
  
  var values = [[inputS.getRange("A2").getValue(),
                 inputS.getRange("B2").getValue(),
                 inputS.getRange("C2").getValue(),
                 inputS.getRange("D2").getValue(),
                 inputS.getRange("E2").getValue(),
                 inputS.getRange("F2").getValue(),
                 inputS.getRange("G2").getValue(),
                 inputS.getRange("H2").getValue(),
                 inputS.getRange("I2").getValue()]];
  outputS.getRange(outputS.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 9).setValues(values);
  ClearCell();
}


  [1]: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MOOczNf-wOZOTo0W-kbWCxkLd3M4udzJQ_fMh7xn1f4/edit#gid=0
```

Comment: As the error message tells you, the function ClearCell which you call in the end of the script seems to not be defined. Have you defined that function yourself somewhere? Or have you used some copy-and-paste code in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue:**

The error can't be more descriptive than that. The function `ClearCell()` at the end of your script is not defined anywhere in your code.

- Also since you are getting a continuous range it is way more efficient to use a single `getRange` instead of multiple `getRange`s.

**Updated solution based on your comment:**

```
function myFunction(){  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var inputS = ss.getSheetByName("Input");
  var outputS = ss.getSheetByName("Output");
  var inputRng = inputS.getRange("A2:I2");
  var values = inputRng.getValues();
  inputRng.clearContent(); // clear input range       
  outputS.getRange(outputS.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! I would like to clear the range of the sheet name "input", as soon as I click on button "Submit". And, no need to clear any content from sheet "output".

Comment: Yes, it kind works. Unfortunately, when I finish filling a cell, it automatically submits it (by clicking on Tab), without the need that I click on the button "Submit". That's not the ideal, as one row of answers on the "input" sheet should be one row of answers on the "output" sheet. That said, I would like only to get range (A2:I2), cleared once I click on "Submit".

Comment: `automatically submits it` ? Do you have an `onEdit` trigger installed for the function ? Post your full code and make sure your provide all the necessary details here when you ask a question to avoid confusion. How exactly do you execute that function?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, and really thanks for your help. Indeed, this function is used in a Google Sheet button. I do draw a button, and then click on "Assign script", and add the one I mentioned above. So the one you corrected works perfectly - it's just that when I click on my keyboard "Tab", then the answer from a column is automatically submitted. But I would only like to get all columns submitted (range A2:I2), when I click on "Submit".

Comment: @RuiFernandes not sure if I follow you and can't reproduce this behaviour. But it sounds like a ui behaviour that can't be changed via script. If you click on the tab button and something happens then that's a Google thing. You can change the ui keyboard shortcuts. But anyway, send me a copy of your sheet and remove all the sensitive information. I think it is easy for you to create a sheet with 9 values and a button.

Comment: I'm really sorry about that. Unfortunately, I'm not able to move this discussion to chat... Therefore, I can't add any files here.

Comment: @RuiFernandes [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65553044/edit) your question to include a link of your spreadsheet file. Create a copy of your current file or reproduce the issue in a new file and share it. Remove all sensitive information. Dummy data that reproduces your issue.

Comment: I have edited the question, and included the link, so that you can access.

Comment: @RuiFernandes make your link public. It is private now.

Comment: Is it now OK? Otherwise, I'm not aware about how to make it public.

Comment: I'm wondering if when submitted, the data can be pasted to another separate file (and not tab). Do you think that there's a way?

Comment: @RuiFernandes hi . Unfortunately, stackoverflow does not allow for follow up questions. Could you please post a separate question and provide me with the link here so I can have a look at it. Thanks and sorry for the incovenience.

Comment: Yes, of course. Here you go : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65583185/copy-data-to-a-separate-file-when-submitted