# Copy data to a separate file when submitted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm wondering if when submitted, the data can be pasted to another separate file (and not tab). Do you think that there's a way?

You can access the file here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FFlsfFyVyQobnbfAgQZA_r5IQeBhgOdK4cBpi5yo77U/edit?usp=sharing

Following code:

```
function myFunction(){  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var inputS = ss.getSheetByName("Input");
  var outputS = ss.getSheetByName("Output");
  var inputRng = inputS.getRange("A2:I2");
  var values = inputRng.getValues();
  inputRng.clearContent(); // clear input range       
  outputS.getRange(outputS.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

You can use [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) to access a different spreadsheet file by its id. As the documentation states:

> For example, the spreadsheet ID in the URL
> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abc1234567/edit#gid=0 is
> "abc1234567".

and assuming that the target spreadsheet has a sheet named `"Output"` then the following code will work. Otherwise, change it to the name of the target sheet.

**Solution:**

```
function ScriptBS() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ts = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id); // put here the id of the target spreadsheet file
  var inputS = ss.getSheetByName("Input");
  var outputS = ts.getSheetByName("Output"); // get sheet Output of the target spreadsheet file
  var inputRng = inputS.getRange("A2:I2");
  var values = inputRng.getValues();
  inputRng.clearContent(); // clear input range       
  outputS.getRange(outputS.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to submit, and get the following error message : TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null.

Comment: Like I said as a code comment and in the explanation itself, make sure that there is a sheet  with the name`"Output"` in the target spreadsheet file.

Comment: Yes, indeed the name is "Output".

Comment: @RuiFernandes in the spreadsheet file you shared the script is the old one. Make sure you saved the changes.

Comment: I have shared a new link in the question... can you access it?

Comment: @RuiFernandes I can access it but don't you see that the code in the **script** is different from the one in my solution?